# What is the effect of creating unit tests during development on time to develop as well as time spent in maintenance activities?

Tags: unit-testing, maintenance, quality

I'm a consultant and I am going to introduce unit tests to all developers at my client site. My goal is to ensure that all new applications should have unit tests for all classes created.

The client has a problem with high maintenance costs from fixing bugs in their existing applications. Their applications have a life span from between 5-15 years in which they continuously add new features.  I'm quite confident that they will benefit greatly from starting with unit tests.

I'm interested in the effect of unit tests on the time and cost of development:

- How much time will writing unit tests as part of the development process add?
- How much time will be saved in maintenance activities (testing and debugging) by having good unit tests?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

> Are there any statistics available to
>   how much longer it will take to
>   develop applications when creating
>   unit test during the development
>   compared to just coding?

There is some very interesting research about this. Read the following whitepaper:

[Realizing quality improvement through test driven
development: results and experiences of four industrial
teams](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/groups/ese/nagappan_tdd.pdf)

The whitepaper and others research from one of its authors, [Nachi Nagappan](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/people/nachin/), are discussed here:
http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/news/features/nagappan-100609.aspx

> The study and its results were published in a paper entitled Realizing quality improvement through test driven development: results and experiences of four industrial teams, by Nagappan and research colleagues E. Michael Maximilien of the IBM Almaden Research Center; Thirumalesh Bhat, principal software-development lead at Microsoft; and Laurie Williams of North Carolina State University. What the research team found was that the TDD teams produced code that was 60 to 90 percent better in terms of defect density than non-TDD teams. They also discovered that TDD teams took longer to complete their projects—15 to 35 percent longer.
>
> “Over a development cycle of 12
>   months, 35 percent is another four
>   months, which is huge,” Nagappan says.
>   “However, the tradeoff is that you
>   reduce post-release maintenance costs
>   significantly, since code quality is
>   so much better. Again, these are
>   decisions that managers have to
>   make—where should they take the hit?
>   But now, they actually have quantified
>   data for making those decisions.”

Additionally, [Jason Gorman](http://parlezuml.com/blog/) has [proposed such an experiment](http://parlezuml.com/blog/?postid=1019) for the Software Craftsmanship conference this year. He's been trying an experiment creating the same application using a TDD and a non-TDD approach and he's [recently blogged about his results](http://parlezuml.com/blog/?postid=1021):

> Over 3 iterations, average time taken to complete the kata without TDD was 28m 40s. Average time with TDD was 25m 27s. Without TDD, on average I made 5.7 passes (delivering into acceptance testing). With TDD, on average I made 1.3 passes (in two attempts, they passed first time, in one it took 2 passes.)
>
> Now, this was a baby experiment, of course. And not exactly laboratory conditions. But I note a couple of interesting things, all the same.

It will be interesting to see the full results of this experiment when more people perform it.

> Are there any statistics available
>   that shows how many hours maintenance
>   decreases when having (good) unit
>   tests?

From the whitepaper above:

> The results of the case studies
>   indicate that the pre-release defect density of the four products decreased between 40% and
>   90% relative to similar projects that did not use the TDD practice.

Comment: I like this answer. I would add that the Language and Test tool can also have a large impact on the TDD time.  For a language like C# , before NCRUNCH, i was not so excited about the benefits of TDD. After seeing and using NCRUNCH.  In my view the trend to do parallel tests are you code is major shift in the effectiveness of such tools. Research based in 2008 may not reflect current tools and their effectiveness.